# imagemagick no error but shows failed [?] "image"

Tags: php, pdf, imagemagick, jpeg

i'm new here but i've already found help for different problems!

i want to generate a jpeg-thumbnail from an online-generated pdf, but the pdf is generated from a php script... so i've to link to a .php script and not to a .pdf file. is that possible?

but my problem first is, when i simply link to a normal .pdf file i get no error, but also no picture. in safari there's only a icon like this: [failure image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J65fi.png)

and firefox shows something like "the image has an error" but that's a text from the browser.

my code:

```
<?php

$file = 'templates/pdf/standard/test_doc.pdf';
$im = new imagick(realpath($file).'[0]');
$im->setImageFormat("jpg");
$im->resizeImage(200,200,1,0);
header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
// start buffering
ob_start();
$thumbnail = $im->getImageBlob();
$contents =  ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

echo "<img src='data:image/jpg;base64,".base64_encode($contents)."' />"

?>
```

Thanx a lot for your help!

Comment: Try with a JPEG/PNG file first because you need `ghostscript` installed to handle PDFs. You can use a URL as an input to **ImageMagick**, just be sure it is trustworthy and know the risks, `$file="http://something/xxx.php"`.

Comment: i'm getting the same result with: $file = 'templates/pdf/standard/06.jpg';

Comment: Ok, your script is not running in the directory you think. Try having it output its current working directory `echo getcwd() . "\n";`, or try adding a slash at the start of your path... `$file="SLASHtemplates..."`

Comment: don't understand what you mean... with echo getcwd() . "\n"; i'm getting the path to my test.php script. that's right!?

Comment: If you get `/scripts` as your working directory, then when you append `templates/pdf/standard` onto that, you will be looking in `/scripts/templates/pdf/standard` for your PDF and I doubt your PDF is under your `/scripts` directory.

Comment: i get "home/fussball/www/clou/test" as the working directory and my pdf/jpg is in "home/fussball/www/clou/test/templates/pdf/standard/"
- that's not wrong? i'm working with a subdomain like http://clou.website.com/ so with that domain i'm in "home/fussball/www/clou/" but that makes no difference, right?

Comment: may i've found the problem? the convert folder from the ImageMagick Script is in "/usr/local/bin/convert" and not "/usr/bin/convert" like normally... maybe that's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i have the solution, maybe this would help somebody:

```
$im = new Imagick();
$im->setResolution(200,200);
$im->readimage('templates/pdf/standard/file.pdf');
$im->setImageFormat('jpeg');    

echo "<img src='data:image/jpeg;base64,".base64_encode($im->getImageBlob())."' width='524px' height='741px'/>";
```